# Converting Python list in JSON

Tags: python, json, list, coding-style

I want to convert a python list into json, here's the input

```
obj=([{'value1': 'a', 'value2': None, 'value3': 'abc', 'value4': 'xyz', 'value5': 'tes', 'value6': None, 'value7': None, 'value8': 'a'}],
[{'value1': 'b', 'value2': None, 'value3': 'abc', 'value4': 'uyt', 'value5': 'tuy', 'value6': None, 'value7': None, 'value8': 'b'}])
```

Desired Output:

```
{ "file": [
   {
    "value1": "a", 
    "value2": None,
    "value3": "abc",
    "value4": "uyt",
    "value5": "tuy",
    "value6": None,
    "value7": None,
    "value8": "a",
   },
   {
    "value1": "b", 
    "value2": None,
    "value3": "abc",
    "value4": "xyz",
    "value5": "tes",
    "value6": None,
    "value7": None,
    "value8": "b",
   }
]
}
```

PS: I followed some existing issues on StackOverflow, but it's not working for me.
Thank you. :)

Comment: can you paste the code that you have tried?

Comment: I had a dictionary at the start, which I converted into the list(given in input section) , now i am unable to get the above desired JSON output.

Comment: why `"value8": "a",` if it should be "b"?

Comment: In what form is the input given? Since there are 2 lists.

Comment: maybe `d['file'] = ls1 + ls2`

Comment: by storing it in a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for any number of lists:

```py
import json

obj = (
    [{
        'value1': 'a', 'value2': None, 'value3': 'abc', 'value4': 'xyz', 'value5': 'tes', 'value6': None, 'value7': None, 'value8': 'a'
    }], 
    [{
        'value1': 'b', 'value2': None, 'value3': 'abc', 'value4': 'uyt', 'value5': 'tuy', 'value6': None, 'value7': None, 'value8': 'b'
    }]
)

result = {'file': []}
for l in obj:
    result['file'].append(l[0])

result_json = json.dumps(result, indent=2)
print(result_json)
```

Output:

```
{
  "file": [
    {
      "value1": "a",
      "value2": null,
      "value3": "abc",
      "value4": "xyz",
      "value5": "tes",
      "value6": null,
      "value7": null,
      "value8": "a"
    },
    {
      "value1": "b",
      "value2": null,
      "value3": "abc",
      "value4": "uyt",
      "value5": "tuy",
      "value6": null,
      "value7": null,
      "value8": "b"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: but in this way we can't give the input from the terminal itself

Comment: @PYC in his question he edited the input to what I'm using in my answer. Also I think there would be no point in giving input like that through terminal, especially if there are a lot of lists.

Comment: oops ‍️, my bad i commented this before he edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

Let's start the day with a simple one:-

```
obj=([{'value1': 'a', 'value2': None, 'value3': 'abc', 'value4': 'xyz', 'value5': 'tes', 'value6': None, 'value7': None, 'value8': 'a'}],
[{'value1': 'b', 'value2': None, 'value3': 'abc', 'value4': 'uyt', 'value5': 'tuy', 'value6': None, 'value7': None, 'value8': 'b'}])
D = {'file': [li[0] for li in obj]}
```

Comment: what if there are N number of lists

Comment: This answers your question as stated. Perhaps you'd like to qualify your original question. Do that and I'll modify my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `defaultdict` as `list` and `json.dumps` like below:

```
from collections import defaultdict

obj=(
    [
        {'value1': 'a', 'value2': None, 'value3': 'abc', 'value4': 'xyz', 'value5': 'tes', 'value6': None, 'value7': None, 'value8': 'a'}
    ],
    [
        {'value1': 'b', 'value2': None, 'value3': 'abc', 'value4': 'uyt', 'value5': 'tuy', 'value6': None, 'value7': None, 'value8': 'b'}
    ])

dct = defaultdict(list)
for l in obj:
    dct['file'].append((l[0]))
    

dct_json = json.dumps(dct, indent=2)
print(dct_json)
```

Output:

```
{
  "file": [
    {
      "value1": "a",
      "value2": null,
      "value3": "abc",
      "value4": "xyz",
      "value5": "tes",
      "value6": null,
      "value7": null,
      "value8": "a"
    },
    {
      "value1": "b",
      "value2": null,
      "value3": "abc",
      "value4": "uyt",
      "value5": "tuy",
      "value6": null,
      "value7": null,
      "value8": "b"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: If you check it's not the desired output sir. these are single quotes, not double.

Comment: OK give me time

Comment: @Mr.Annonymous again edited answer base on your edited question

Comment: I ain't saying it's incorrect. but I can only mark one as correct

Comment: @Mr.Annonymous thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 1):

Some code might be redundant, but I'll do it like this:

```py
import json

obj=([{'value1': 'a', 'value2': None, 'value3': 'abc'}], [{'value1': 'b', 'value2': None, 'value3': 'abc'}])

obj_list = [i[0] for i in obj]
dict1 = {"file": obj_list}

json_object = json.dumps(dict1, indent=1)
print(json_object)
```

Answer (score 1):

here's the code that you're looking for

```
import json

obj=([{'value1': 'a', 'value2': None, 'value3': 'abc', 'value4': 'xyz', 'value5': 'tes', 'value6': None, 'value7': None, 'value8': 'a'}],[{'value1': 'b', 'value2': None, 'value3': 'abc', 'value4': 'uyt', 'value5': 'tuy', 'value6': None, 'value7': None, 'value8': 'b'}])
file = {"file": []}
file['file'] = [i for i in obj]
print(json.dumps(file, indent=2, sort_keys=True))
```

you can also either delete sort_keys argument or just set it to false if you don't want it to sort the things

**PS:** If you want to reduce the indent reduce 2 to something lower